# Allow non-logged in users to see a future post after clicking on a list of future posts

Tags: custom-post-types, posts, theme-development, pages, scheduled-posts

I have been able to list out pages that are set for future in a custom template like this:

```
query_posts('post_type=page&post_status=future&posts_per_page=100&order=asc&orderby=date&meta_key=_wp_page_template&meta_value=show.php');
```

However, when I try to then click on one of the pages listed there I get a 404 (as a non-logged-in user).

How do I alter a thematic `page.php` template to show a future page?

We are already using a bunch of things in `function.php` and have a special page template for this particular type of post...

I tried adding the following to the `functions.php` with `add_filter`, but it didn't help:

```
function show_future_where($where) {
    return $where . ' AND (wp_posts.post_status = \'publish\' OR wp_posts.post_status = \'future\')';
}
```

BTW, I saw a post about automatically setting a post with a future date would be overridden with 'published' state, but couldn't get that to work.

If I can edit the page template is there something else I can do?

I am using 3.3, if that helps.

Thanks.

Comment: [Here is a solution](http://w4dev.com/wp/show-future-posts-not-loggedin-user/)

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
$my_query = new WP_Query(array(
    'post_status' => 'future',
    'order' => 'DESC',
    'posts_per_page' => 1,
));
while ($my_query->have_posts()) {
    $my_query->the_post();
    the_date();
    echo ' - ';
    the_title();
}
wp_reset_postdata();
```

or this: http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/show-future-posts-on-single-post/

Comment: Thanks for responding, but this seems to show the last five posts that are marked future, right? I wanted to just show one post (page, actually) that is marked future on it's single post page... am I misunderstanding the solution?

Comment: @Chris Butler: Change showposts=5 to showposts=1 and put the full code into a Page Template(showposts=5)

Comment: You should use `posts_per_page` param, and not `showposts`. The latter one is deprecated (it was replaced in 2.1, I guess)